# Cloud SQL (postgres) - Fetching metrics tagged with BETA

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-sdk

Have been trying to fetch metrics for my Cloud SQL (postgres) instance to get insights into query performance, but I'm unable to find a way to fetch metrics that are in BETA and ALPHA stage.

For example, the metric
`database/postgresql/insights/perquery/execution_time` is listed in the [google cloud metrics page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudsql) but does not show up in the metrics explorer.

Have tried fetching the metrics using the java sdk which seems to accept/recognise the request and the metric name but does not return any time-series data

Curious to know if BETA/ALPHA metrics needs additional configuration to be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL metrics became available in the metrics explorer and the SDK after enabling `Query Insights` in the google cloud console.

Although this looks obvious, would be good to have a note mentioning this in the [google metrics page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp)